# Typescript variable syntax error on terminal

Tags: node.js, typescript, terminal, visual-studio-code

i try to learn TypeScript on Visual Studio Code. But i get an sim error that i don't understand beacuse of defining variable. I'm define as that:

```
let year:number = 2015
```

I get a syntax error on terminal beacuse i'm put a colon and write the variable type after the variable name.

[image: error]

How can i correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i correct this error?

Don't run `.ts` files directly.

## Solution

Compile to js before running. e.g.

```
tsc srcfiles
```

## More

Quickstart : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html

Answer (score 0):

As the question is quite old,, but I am answering for other developers like me who stuck with same issue. Enhancement in @basarat's answer:
You need to

> Compile .ts file

&

> Run .js file

Example: You have created a typescript file HelloWorld.ts

When you want to compile do

```
tsc HelloWorld.ts
```

.js file will be generate. Then to run your code do the following

```
node HelloWorld.js
```

Voila!!